# Android: Why my code is looping?

Tags: java, android, infinite-loop

I have a problem, i made this:

```
public class Analizzatore extends Activity {

TextView tvRisultato;
Button bCheck;
EditText oneri, interessi, dataAnno, numeri;
float oneriF, interessiF, numeriF, TEG;
int dataAnnoInt, dataMeseInt;
String oneriS, interessiS, numeriS, dataAnnoS, testoNonUsurato,
        testoUsurato;
Date dateParsed;
RadioGroup classeImporto, trimestre;
Toast toast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.analizzatore);

    // Initilization
    tvRisultato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRisultato);

    oneri = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOneri);
    interessi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInteressi);
    dataAnno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDataAnno);
    numeri = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumeri);

    testoNonUsurato = "Non usurato";
    testoUsurato = "Usurato";

    trimestre = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgTrimestre);
    classeImporto = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    bCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCheck);

    bCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Assegna tutti i dati alle rispettive Stringhe per la mail
            oneriS = oneri.getText().toString();
            interessiS = interessi.getText().toString();
            dataAnnoS = dataAnno.getText().toString();
            numeriS = numeri.getText().toString();

            // Controlla il trimestre dai RadioButtons e poi assegna un int
            // a dataMeseInt
            if (trimestre.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.primo) {
                dataMeseInt = 3;
            }
            if (trimestre.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.secondo) {
                dataMeseInt = 6;
            }
            if (trimestre.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.terzo) {
                dataMeseInt = 9;
            }
            if (trimestre.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.quarto) {
                dataMeseInt = 12;
            }

            // Inizializza i dati usando le stringhe per la mail
            dataAnnoInt = Integer.parseInt(dataAnnoS);
            numeriF = Float.parseFloat(numeriS);
            oneriF = Float.parseFloat(oneriS);
            interessiF = Float.parseFloat(interessiS);

            Calcolo();
        }
    });
}

protected void Calcolo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Calcolo del TEG
    TEG = ((interessiF + oneriF) * 36500) / numeriF;

    CheckDate();
}

// Controlla la data dello scalare, partendo dall'anno per poi controllare
// anche il trimestre
private void CheckDate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (dataAnnoInt) {
    case (2003): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.34 + (12.34 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.73 + (9.73 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 11.95 + (11.95 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.37) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.15 + (12.15 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.46 + (9.46 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 11.90 + (11.90 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.26 + (9.26 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2004): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.41 + (12.41 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.50 + (9.50 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.16 + (12.16 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.42 + (9.42 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.34 + (12.34 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.47 + (9.47 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.32 + (12.32 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.44 + (9.44 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2005): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.47 + (12.47 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.51 + (9.51 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.43 + (12.43 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.50 + (9.50 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.63 + (12.63 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.52 + (9.52 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.54 + (12.54 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.37 + (9.37 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2006): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.58 + (12.58 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.38 + (9.38 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.87 + (12.87 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.49 + (9.49 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.68 + (12.68 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.58 + (9.58 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 13.08 + (13.08 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.80 + (9.80 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2007): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 13.16 + (13.16 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.94 + (9.94 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 13.09 + (13.09 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.90 + (9.90 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 13.04 + (13.04 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.96 + (9.96 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 13.10 + (13.10 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.95 + (9.95 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2008): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 13.00 + (13.00 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.84 + (9.84 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.91 + (12.91 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.88 + (9.88 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.97 + (12.97 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.87 + (9.87 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 13.27 + (13.27 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 10.09 + (10.09 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2009): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.27 + (12.27 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.12 + (9.12 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 11.79 + (11.79 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 8.62 + (8.62 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 11.59 + (11.59 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 8.32 + (8.32 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 11.76 + (11.76 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 8.51 + (8.51 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2010): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.85 + (12.85 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.59 + (9.59 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 12.48 + (12.48 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.82 + (9.82 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 11.50 + (11.50 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.14 + (9.14 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 11.38 + (11.38 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.15 + (9.15 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2011): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 11.13 + (11.13 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.02 + (9.02 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 11.10 + (11.10 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 9.09 + (0.09 / 2)) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 18.05) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 15.59) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 17.84) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 15.53) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2012): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 17.85) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 16.39) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 17.75) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 15.64) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 17.59) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 15.81) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 18.05) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 16.41) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    case (2013): {
        switch (dataMeseInt) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 18.24) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 16.74) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 18.15) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 16.68) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 1000) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 1000) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12: {
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio0) {
                if (TEG > 1000) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
            if (classeImporto.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio1) {
                if (TEG > 1000) {
                    ScalareUsurato();
                } else {
                    ScalareNonUsurato();
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}

// In caso non ci fosse usura:
private void ScalareNonUsurato() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    createDialog(testoNonUsurato);

    tvRisultato.setText(testoNonUsurato.toString());
}

// In caso ci fosse usura:
private void ScalareUsurato() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    createDialog(testoUsurato);

    tvRisultato.setText(testoUsurato.toString());
}

private void createDialog(String testo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), testo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}
```

}

With this code i get infinite Toasts.
The first time i tought it was a problem with the toast, so i decided to make a new activity to show the result, and then i understood that my code was looping, cause it was opening infinite Activitys.

Can you help me, and tell me why my codeis looping?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't have `break` in your switch.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone, i didn't noticed the breaks was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think its looping it's just going through all  cases because you didn't put `break` or `return`s in !

I.e.:

```
switch(myVar){
   case 1:
     //do something
   break;
   case 2:
     // do something different 
   break;
   default:
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

it's not a loop, you don't have any `break`; in your `switch`.

Comment: Talk about a pass-through gone bad!